# Is a finite group given by its character table if its Sylow subgroups are so?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, characters

As pointed out by Mikko Korhonen in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/326735/34538), Özdem Çelik proved (in 1976 [here](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0470050)) that a finite group whose Sylow subgroups are cyclic (called a [Z-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-group)) is determined by its character table.

Now there are many results and conjectures relating character tables and Sylow subgroups (see [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-981-13-2047-7_10) of Gabriel Navarro), the most famous being perhaps the [McKay conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McKay_conjecture).

This leads to wonder whether Çelik's theorem can be extended*.

**Question 1**: Is a finite group determined by its character table **only if** its Sylow subgroups are so?
*Answer* (Alex B.): No.

**Question 2**: Is a finite group not in a Brauer pair **only if** its Sylow subgroups are so?
(negative answer suspected by Alex B.)

***Question 3**: Is a finite group determined by its character table **if** its Sylow subgroups are so?
(it is this question which wonders whether Çelik's theorem can be extended)

**Question 4**: Is a finite group not in a Brauer pair **if** its Sylow subgroups are so?

Comment: Çelik's paper [MR0470050](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0470050) is old and very hard to find. Can anyone having a copy put it in comment?

Answer (score 6):

The answer to the first question is negative. The group ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ has a $2$-Sylow subgroup isomorphic to $Q_8$, which is not determined by its character table, but ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ is the only group with its character table.

I strongly suspect that the answer to the second question is also negative, and it should be not too hard to check this computationally, using the following strategy, but I have not attempted this.

One way of seeing how the counterexample above worked is this: the group $Q_8$ has an outer automoprhism of order $3$ (cyclicly permuting $i$, $j$, and $k$), and ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ is a semidirect product of $Q_8$ and $C_3$, with the action given by this automorphism. On the other hand, $D_8$ has no automorphisms of order $3$, so one cannot produce an analogous construction with this cousin of $Q_8$. That makes it "unlikely" (in no precise sense) that there is another group with the same character table as ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$.

I have checked that the group that [Lux and Pahlings](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/representations-of-groups/9EF74E145F6DE62ACD6047953B09CCBB) call $G_{3378}$ in Theorem 2.6.2 has an automorphism $\alpha$ of order $3$, while the other group in the Brauer pair, $G_{3380}$, does not. So I would conjecture that the group $G_{3378}\rtimes\langle \alpha\rangle$ is determined by its character table. This is a group of order $768$, so magma has the complete list of all groups of this order, and the conjecture should not be too hard to check, but I have not done that.

Comment: We can deduce the Grothendieck ring of a finite group from its character table. Now a finite group $G$ is simple iff its Grothendieck ring is simple. So, if there is no simple group of order $|G|$ non-isomorphic to $G$ then $G$ is determined by its character table (in fact it's true for any finite simple group by [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/57455/34538)). So any finite simple group with a Sylow not determined by its character table will be a counter-example to Q1: $PSL_2(7) \supset D_8$, $A_6 \supset D_8$. For Q2 we need to find a simple group with a Sylow in a Brauer pair.